# Не работает веб-сервис на сервере, локально все окей

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, веб-служба

Cделал Веб-сервис для тестирования одного сайта, с помощью библиотеки selenium. Вызвал службу у себя на компьютере, все замечательно работает. Опубликовал на сервер - появились ошибки. Когда я вызываю этот метод, как клиент,просто вызвав метод из обычного приложения, у меня появляется следующая ошибка.

[image: Exception timeout]

Я подключил логи, для просмотра ошибок, где происходит исключение. Исходя из логов, ошибка происходит при нажатии на кнопку на форме. Код, где я нажимаю на эту кнопку, привел ниже.
Далее, если смотреть на логи, то программа продолжает выполняться и возвращает правильный результат. Но я не могу понять почему, когда я вызываю этот метод, появляется ошибка.

Испробовал, несколько способов нажатия на кнопку - ошибка одна и та-же. Надеюсь на вашу помощь.

```
 IWebElement submit = wait.Until<IWebElement>((d) => { return d.FindElement(By.Id("submitbutton")); });
  try
            {
                //password.SendKeys(Keys.Enter);

                submit.Click(); // вот тут вылетает
            }
            catch (Exception ee)
            {
                log.Error(ee);
            }
```

Comment: у вас и клиент и сервер и приложение и сервис, и вот это `приложение вылетает при нажатии на кнопку, но дальше выполняется`. Вы как то переформулируйте вопрос, а то сейчас это просто поток мыслей, понятный только вам.

Comment: Написал более понятно, надеюсь

Comment: куда опубликовали свой сервис? а какой сайт он тестировать должен, где он расположен?

Comment: @Konst сервер компании в которой работаю, сайт сторонний, расположен в России, доступа к этому сайту нет

Comment: стоит проверить доступность тестируемого сайта со стороны сервера, где развёрнут ваш selenuim rc

Comment: @Konst Все доступно, иначе я бы в логах увидел ошибку. Плюс, сервис после таймаута дальше выполняется, это видно по логам на сервере.